# How to include SDL to clion project?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, sdl

I've just installed Clion and it uses CMake and I've got problems with including external libraries properly. I've never used CMake before and now I am struggling with it. I've been using premake for a while.

I want to have SDL as a git submodule from this repository https://github.com/davidsiaw/SDL2

I've been looking for an answer for hours and still cannot get it right. I am a complete noob in cmake.

my project looks like this:

```
ProjectName/
|--- CMakeLists.txt
|
|--- src/
     |--- main.cpp
     |--- CMakeLists.txt
|
|--- Dependencies/
     |--- SDL2
```

my src cmake lists

```
add_executable(ProjectName main.cpp)
```

and the main CMake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(ProjectName)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include_directories(Dependencies/SDL2/include)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(Dependencies/SDL2)

target_link_libraries(ProjectName PRIVATE SDL2main)
target_link_libraries(ProjectName PRIVATE SDL2)
```

and main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "SDL.h"

int main(int* argc, char* args[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error message

```
In file included from /cygdrive/c/Users/mprze/OneDrive/Pulpit/ProjectName/Dependencies/SDL2/src/./SDL_internal.h:48,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Users/mprze/OneDrive/Pulpit/ProjectName/Dependencies/SDL2/src/SDL.c:21:
/cygdrive/c/Users/mprze/OneDrive/Pulpit/ProjectName/Dependencies/SDL2/include/SDL_config.h:50:2: error: #error Wrong SDL_config.h, check your include path?
```

How to add it properly?

Comment: This probably won't fix the compilation error but you seem to have forgotten the ending quote in the string you output in your `main` function.

Comment: Have you tried to build you clone of SDL2 as **standalone** project (by running `cmake` with SDL2 source directory, not with the source directory of your project)? It could be that the clone itself is bugged.

Comment: @NathanMills right, fixed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, I have. It builds fine.

Comment: Ok, it seems your `include_directories(Dependencies/SDL2/include)` confuses SDL2 project: it adds include directory which is not intended to be used by SDL2 itself. Either move `include_directories` call **after** `add_subdirectory(Dependencies/SDL2)`, or replace this call with `target_include_directories` for appropriate target.

Comment: Ok, I replaced include_directories with target_include_directories and it gives me other errors: `CMakeFiles/SDL2.dir/src/dynapi/SDL_dynapi.c.o:SDL_dynapi.c:(.rdata$.refptr.SDL_SetWindowsMessageHook_REAL[.refptr.SDL_SetWindowsMessageHook_REAL]+0x0): undefined reference to SDL_SetWindowsMessageHook_REAL`

and the same message but with `SDL_DXGIGetOutputInfo_REAL` and `SDL_Direct3D9GetAdapterIndex_REAL`, and `SDL_UnregisterApp_REAL`, and `SDL_RegisterApp_REAL`, and one more `undefined reference to WIN_SetError`